# Is SQL unknown identical to NULL?

Tags: sql, null, three-valued-logic

I'm confused what does UNKNOWN means in SQL in 3 valued logic. Does it mean NULL actually? Is it true that NULL and UNKNOWN can be interchangeable in all boolean contexts?

Comment: No, unknown is unknown. It's not null. Try here for a start https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/sql-and-the-snare-of-three-valued-logic/

Comment: The official SQL Standard "does not make a distinction between the null value of the boolean data type and the truth value Unknown" (§4.5 ISO/IEC 9075-2:2016) it goes on to say "they may be used interchangeably to mean exactly the same thing".

Comment: @sirain RDBMS support for Boolean type is optional, and NULL can be in any column data type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_data_type#SQL):

> NULL BOOLEAN and UNKNOWN "may be used interchangeably to mean exactly the same thing"

However, some database systems don't in fact implement SQL's boolean data type (it's optional) and in most of those systems, there is no circumstance where you'd encounter both `UNKNOWN`s and `NULL`s within the same context - `UNKNOWN`s only appear when evaluating predicates.

The are various tools you can use to try to eliminate `NULL`s, such as `COALESCE` or `IS [NOT] NULL`. Most of these cannot be used in the context of evaluating predicates and so will never be used with an `UNKNOWN` value. E.g. if you have a query like:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    TableA
WHERE A = 'B'
```

And you know that there are some `NULL` `A` values which are thus causing the `WHERE` clause predicate to produce `UNKNOWN`, you **cannot** write:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    TableA
WHERE COALESCE(A = 'B',TRUE)
```

To eliminate the `UNKNOWN`.

Comment: Your last example about coalesce is actually workable in MySQL which supports predicate expressions as values.

Comment: Wikipedia is not a source. What did the article cite?

Answer (score 9):

Simple answer:

```
3 == 2 => FALSE
3 == 3 => TRUE
NULL == 3 => UNKNOWN
3 == NULL => UNKNOWN
NULL == NULL => UNKNOWN
```

Expression with `NULL` on either side or both evaluates to `UNKNOWN`.

For example if you have a table:

```
Employees(id, country)
1, USA
2, USA
3, Canada
4, NULL
```

Say your boss asks you to select all employees that don't live in USA. You write:

```
select * from Employees
where country <> 'USA'
```

and get:

```
3, Canada
```

Why 4 is not selected? Because in `WHERE` clause only rows are returned where expression evaluates to `TRUE`:

```
1. USA <> 'USA' => FALSE -- don't return this row
2. USA <> 'USA' => FALSE -- don't return this row
3. CANADA <> 'USA' => TRUE -- return this row
4. NULL <> 'USA' => UNKNOWN -- don't return this row
```

It is not only for equality or inequality. For any [predicate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189523.aspx)

Comment: but in my db comparison with null also returns null where it should be unknown, so I am confused where unknown actually is the same thing as null

Comment: Which `RDBMS` ?

Comment: @MichaelTsang - in [tag:mysql], `NULL` and `UNKNOWN` are treated the same. As I indicate in my answer, this is by no means universal across SQL database systems.

Answer (score 1):

Read this link hope its helpfull for you

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt204037.aspx